Fetch child component dynamically
I'm having a hard time fetching a child component dynamically. Please help and tell me what I'm doing wrong. The dynamic-container is just empty, although there was no error...
MAIN COMPONENT:
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item" indexVar="i">
        <div class="dynamic-container" data-id="{!item.id}">xx</div>
    </aura:iteration>

controller:
    createChildComponents: function(component) {
        var childComponentName = component.get("v.cWidgetName");
        var items = component.get("v.items");

        if (items && items.length > 0) {
            items.forEach(function(item) {
                var container = $(document).find('.dynamic-container[data-id="' + item.id + '"]');
                if (container) {
                    $A.createComponent(
                        childComponentName,
                        {
                            "title": 'this',
                            "rID": item.id 
                        },
                        function(newComponent, status, errorMessage) {
                            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                $(newComponent).appendTo(container);
                            } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.");
                            } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        }

    }

the child component is:
    <aura:component controller="GetKAPSIApplicationVotingController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
        <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.CYRILjQuery3}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}"/>
    
        <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.init}" />
        
        <aura:attribute name="rID" type="String"/>
        <aura:attribute name="title" type="String" /> 
    
        <!-- body here -->
        
    </aura:component>


For performance reasons, you should use $A.createComponents rather than $A.createComponent. Second, it is traditional to use Aura.Component[] attributes to show the elements.
<aura:attribute name="children" type="Aura.Component[]" access="global" />
{!v.children}

And in your controller/helper:
var childComponentName = component.get("v.cWidgetName");
var items = component.get("v.items");
$A.createComponents(
  items.map((item) => [childComponentName, { title: 'this', rID: item.id }]),
  function(newComponents, status, errorMessages) {
   // Error handling omitted //
    component.set("v.children", newComponents);
  }
);

There's no need for jQuery/JavaScript to manipulate the DOM directly. If you still need the components wrapped, you can also create DIV elements and nest them together.
For additional information, see Dynamically Creating Components.
